# Division in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

So my question is, how can divide figures in one column to a specific "cell". I am sure that there is a dax formula that can do this just not sure which. Please help.

[image: Screen Shot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some articles describing how to calculate subtotals values with DAX in PBI.

- https://powerpivotpro.com/2013/07/writing-a-subtotal-calc-column-aka-the-simplest-use-of-the-earlier-function/
- https://powerpivotpro.com/2012/03/subtotals-and-grand-totals-that-add-up-correctly/